# desabilitar duplo clique em todo site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

É possível desabilitar o duplo clique em todo o site e em qualquer elemento?
Isso é possível com jQuery ou HTML? Quero evitar que o usuário dê 2 cliques seguidos em links, botões e etc.

Comment: Você quer impedir que o usuário selecione texto no seu sitema/sistema?

Comment: A princípio sim é possível mas e se o usuário desabilitar JS no navegador? Qual deveria ser o comportamento do site?

Comment: Se o problema for clicar 2x em um botão e não em textos seria melhor desabilitar o link/botão após o primeiro clique, o que acha?

Comment: Eu acho que é má idéia. Deixa o browser seguir o comportamento padrão dele, deixa o html cumprir sua função... Bloquear cliques adicionais no browser parece ser enjambração pra resolver problema que deveria ser resolvido em outro lugar - além de não garantir nada por vários motivos (o javascript pode ser violado no browser, pode ser desabilitado, pode quebrar por um erro e o bloqueio nem ser implementado...). Acho que o ideal é que o sistema faça o que tiver que fazer no primeiro clique e não deixe que cliques adicionais corrompam os dados.

Comment: @jean serial legal exibir uma mensagem ao usuário. Afinal o JS tem que ser obrigatório, pois o front-end inteiro e feito com jquery.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly com faço para desabilitar os link e botões após o 1º clique?

Comment: @Caffé Exatamente! Infelizmente comentário não são o lugar p/ chat mas era ai mesmo onde eu queria chegar. OP pode conseguir desabilitar o duplo clique mas isso tem grande change de gerar problemas no futuro enquanto que um tratamento da entrada de dados seria mais correto

Comment: @Caffé apesar de concordar - em parte - com você, também sou a favor de evitar duplos cliques em algumas situações. Imagine que você vai enviar um fomulário para criar uma conta. Não vejo problema em bloquear o botão ao primeiro clique, até por que isso pode ser usado para dar um feedback visual ao usuário, melhorando o UX, informando que a ação dele foi executada e está sendo processada. Mas enfim, são opiniões e opções de desenvolvimento, apenas para mostrar outra visão para o "problema".

Comment: @CelsomTrindade não foi essa a pergunta, certo? A pergunta diz "em todo o site" incluindo links, o que seria o oposto de dar uma boa experiência ao usuário. Se há uma requisição ajax em um botão, por exemplo, você pode facilmente desabilitar este botão e ainda incluir um indicador de atividade em andamento durante a requisição ajax. Desabilitar todo o site como diz a pergunta ou mesmo dar aquela esmaecida na tela desabilitando qualquer interação só acontece nos piores sites que usamos por aí. E se não for durante requisição ajax mas sim durante submit da página ou navegação, pior ainda.

Comment: @Caffé sim sim. Por isso que disse que concordo com você em parte e a favor do bloqueio só em algumas situações.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode desabilitar o elemento `button` por ex. depois do `click` e habilitar ele novamente após 2 segundos (por ex.)

```js
function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementById("linha").innerHTML += "<p>adicionado linha</p>";

    //Desabilita o botao
    e.disabled = true;
    
    //Habilita novamente após dois segundos (2000) ms
    setTimeout(function(){
      toggleDisabled(e)
    },2000);
}

function toggleDisabled(elem){
  elem.disabled = !elem.disabled;
}
```

```html
<p>Texto de testes</p>
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" id="btn">Clique</button>
<div id="linha"></div>
```

Comment: Ou ao final da função (ou de alguma requisição ajax, por exemplo), que seria o mais ideal, pois não só desabilita o duplo clique como evita um novo clique em caso de demora na execução da função.

Comment: andrepaulo sua idéia é muito boa, é exatamente o que eu estou querendo. Porém preciso tirar uma dúvida, como posso usar ela em todas as tag `button` e dentro de um link assim: `<div onclick="document.location='pagina.html'">menu</div>`?

Comment: Como foi comentado na questão que se utiliza jQuery, acho que vale a edição da resposta para jQuery, vai simplificar bastante o código.